# How to close java console in mac when page get navigates to other page.?

Tags: java, macos, applet, jvm

I have an applet code. That i added to one of my web-application, when i click tab called Enrollment, applet will load and java console will open. it is happening.
And when i click other tab this java console has close. and again if i click Enrollment tab again new Java console has open.

How to do it please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

> How to close java console in mac when page get navigates to other page.?

The console disappearing is subject to decisions by the JVM.  Typically it will be left on-screen as long as the JVM runs, and that is significantly later than when the user navigates away from the page.

The console can be configured (by the user or their system administrator) to not show at all.  Anything beyond visible/not visible is not open to our control and you should not worry about, it is just wasting time.

Comment: @user3522207: One Mac, see `System Preferenes > Java > Java Control Panel > Advanced`.